# Como resolver problema de parada repentina do app?

Tags: android, app, firebase

Estou criando um app no Android Studio e sempre que testo ele para ver o andamento ele não roda, dá uma parada.

> app (nome do app) stopped.

No Logcat aparece isso:

> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for    com.google.firebase.auth not found. 
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires   9877000 but found 9875480
>      Application terminated.

Comment: vc precisa entrar na pagina do google developers e baixar o arquivo de configuração json para o projeto que voce definiu para usar com o firebase e colocar ele na pasta raiz do projeto

Comment: `Google Play services out of date`
O seu emulador esta com o google play desatualizado...
Não sei bem como faz para atualizar isso, se consegue baixar uma atualização dentro do próprio emulador, ou se precisa criar um outro com ele já atualizado.

Comment: entao e isso...no caso no json eu ja fiz isso...mas vou ver como faz pra atualizar o google play